# Center polygon in open layers - osm api

Tags: javascript, jquery, openlayers, openstreetmap

I have tried with centering polygon in open layers with the following function-

```
function centerIn(longitude,latitude){
lonlat = new OpenLayers.LonLat(longitude, latitude).transform(
    new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"), // transform from WGS 1984
    new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913") // to Spherical Mercator Projection
);
map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(lonlat.lon, lonlat.lat), 10);
map.zoomTo(theZoom);
}
```

centerIn(0.99689177607425,44.1216337491133);

My polygon bounds are -
1.18915251826175,44.069361365345
1.12048796748053,43.941939265001
1.45900420283204,43.9394671408999

While executing it is pointing to the edges of the polygon.Not the center of polygon.Could anybody suggest me some solutions to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your question I feel that you need to get the bounds of the polygon.I have used with the attributes to get the bounds.
And then zoom into the map.

```
function centerPolygon(){
 console.log('centerPolygon');
 var features_poly=vectorLayer.getFeaturesByAttribute('id',3);
 //console.log(features_poly[0].geometry.bounds);
 var bounds=features_poly[0].geometry.bounds;
 map.zoomToExtent(bounds);

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.It was very helpful.